# How to search through an object and return a value that can be appended to HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make an art quote calculator and am having trouble with the following code. I want the calculateQuote function to traverse through the costs object using the value of different select elements in order to find the right price and then display that price. However, I'm running into an error somewhere in the submit.onclick portion I believe. When I run the code, at that step, nothing gets populated onto the page.

```
const costs = {
        "painting": {
            "simple": {
                "_10x10": "25", 
                "_11x14": "55", 
                "_16x20": "75", 
                "_18x24": "100"},
            "complex": {
                "_10x10": "55", 
                "_11x14": "75", 
                "_16x20": "100", 
                "_18x24": "150-250"}
        },
    
        "pencil": {
            "simple": {
                "_11x14": "150"},
            "complex": {
                "_11x14": "150"}
        },
    
        "mural": {
            "simple": {
                "_3x5": "200-300", 
                "_8x12": "750", 
                "_10x12": "950", 
                "_8x24": "1,500"},
            "complex": {
                "_3x5": "500", 
                "_8x12": "1,150", 
                "_10x12": "1,400", 
                "_8x24": "2,300"}
        }
    }
    
    
        function calculateQuote(){
          if(typeElement.value === "painting"){
            const finalquote = costs.typeValue.complexityValue.paintingSizeValue;
          } else if(typeElement.value === "pencil"){
            const finalquote = costs.typeValue.complexityValue.pencilSizeValue;
          } else {
            const finalquote = costs.typeValue.complexityValue.muralSizeValue;
          }
          return finalquote;
        }
    
        submit.onclick = function(){
          hideDiv(complexityElement);
          hideDiv(complexityLabelElement);
          hideDiv(submit);
          let clientQuote = document.createElement('p');
          clientQuote.innerHTML = calculateQuote();
          quoteDiv.appendChild(clientQuote);
          quoteDiv.style.display = "block";
        }
```

Comment: Always check your browser console for errors before posting questions. You do not have a `finalquote` in scope when you return in `calculateQuote` - variables declared with `const` are only visible within the block they're declared in

Comment: Okay, thank you. Sorry about that. So would let be the one to use here?

Comment: No, `let` has block scope as well. Best approach would be to not declare variables at all and just `return` the value immediately